# Difference between beat and normal frequency?

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, frequency

**Question**

I was doing some physics problem regarding waves and the problem was

> Assume the speed of sound is 340 m/s. One stereo loudspeaker produces a sound with a wavelength of 0.68 meters while the other speaker produces sound with a wavelength of 0.65 m. What would be the resulting beat frequency?

So I thought the answer was 500 but the book talked about the beat frequency

What is a beat frequency?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(acoustics)

Comment: beat frequency is the difference in frequency between two waves of similar frequency

Comment: Nice demonstration of beats towards the end of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRpN9uLiouI